# Rails: Update join table custom attribute when a new record is created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

Lets say I have two models: `Performance` and `Band`, and to connect the two I have a join table called `performers`. My ActiveRecord models are setup as follows:

```
class Band < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :performers
  has_many :performances, through: :performers, dependent: :destroy
end

class Performance < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :performers
  has_many :bands, through: :performers, dependent: :destroy
end

class Performer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :band
  belongs_to :performance
end
```

Now the tricky part. I have a custom attribute called `permissions` in the `performers` table that captures the permission levels (owner, editor, viewer) for a performer, which defines who can make changes to a performance. Which brings me to my question: when a band creates a new performance, how can I set a value on the join table during creation e.g.

```
    def create
      performance = Performance.new(performance_params)
      # here I add a performance to a band's performances, which creates a new performer record
      band.performances << performance
      # what I would also like to do (at the same time if possible) is also define the permission level 
      # during creation something like but:
      performer = band.performers.last
      performer.permissions = 'owner'
      performer.save
      render json: serialize(performance), status: 200 
    end
```

Is there something in Rails that can let me modify a join tables attribute during creation of an association?

EDIT

For reference, right now I do:

```
def create
     performance = Performance.new(performance_params)
     performer = Performer.new
     performer.band = Band.find(params[:band_id])
     performer.permissions = 'owner'
     performance.performers << performer
     performance.save!
     render json: serialize(performance), status: 200
end
```

But was wondering if there was something simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either [Association Callbacks](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-callbacks) on `has_many` or add appropriate [callback](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html) to `Performer` model as it's still created as a model even it's joining one.

Something like:

```rb
class Performer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :band
  belongs_to :performance

  before_create :set_permissions

  private

  def set_permissions
    self.permissions = 'owner'
  end
end
```

Comment: This works if the permissions are always 'owner' on create, but what if in another controller I want to add a performer to an existing performance but I want that performer to only be a 'viewer'?

Comment: I would say that your last snippet is the best way to go then. You can extend my solution to something like looking up on virtual attribute on `performance` and set it in a controller, but I guess it'll be even more confusing. if rules are static - first one `owner` rest are `viewer`s, you can look up it in `set_permissions`.